# Should oAuth 2.0 revoke older Authorization Codes if new code requested

Tags: oauth-2.0

I can't figure out if oAuth 2.0 server should revoke old Authorization Codes (*not Authorization Tokens*) when new code requested? Also I can't figure out in what format oAuth server should show the error if valid **redirect_uri** parameter not specified neither registered in app settings.

Thank you for helping me understand this RFC.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, your questions are not covered by the specs, so the answers below reflects only my personal opinion on a practical implementation.

A client may legally request several authorization codes with different scopes. You can argue if this makes sense (though I think it does), but the standard does not forbid it. Consequently, I think old codes should be revoked only if a client resends a request (i.e. with exactly the same request details: client id, redirect uri, scopes).

For missing redirect_uri, servers should return HTTP 400 Bad Request and include error details in the message body (and/or appropriate HTTP headers).

Comment: If I understood correctly Authorization Code should have a small TTL. Then it doesn't make sense to allow multiple authorization codes with different scopes if each code lives for only 1-10 minutes? In RFC it said that client should exchange Authorization Code for Authorization Token as soon as possible.

Comment: A short TTL does not contradict to several requests, they all could be served in a short period. However, giving a second thought I realized that the authorization code OAuth scenario requires explicit user approval (i.e. user interaction). As the scenario redirects the user from the client webapp to the auth server, it's impossible for the client to request for another token until the result of the first request is retrieved. Consequently, you should revoke the code for a new request from the same client.